# Can we use RStudio's viewer within a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

**Problem**: `plot`ing images is usually long in R (user-side), even when using `raster`.

**Possible trail**: With images as objects of class `magick-image`, one can use RStudio's viewer as proposed/implemented in the `magick`'s [package vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html#preview).

There is an open [issue on `magick`'s github repos](https://github.com/ropensci/magick/issues/16) dedicated to this particular `magick`+ `shiny` combination and detailing the rationale.

**What I have found**: [Rstudio's support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/202133558-Extending-RStudio-with-the-Viewer-Pane) indicates how to *display* a shiny app within the viewer but I'm looking for the opposite: display an efficient viewer within a shiny app.

**Question**:  is there a generic way to integrate RStudio's viewer (or equivalent) within a shiny app?

**(By the way) question**: can we retrieve clicked coordinates and other events from the viewer (or equivalent)?

Comment: As you are aware, the [source code to RStudio is on GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio) too so ...

Comment: I doubt this is possible; the Viewer pane is part of the IDE (I'm guessing some type of `QWidget`). You should elaborate on what you mean by *"or equivalent"*, however. What functionality are you looking for specifically?

Comment: @Dirk: well yes, but what od you mean? that I ask there or that I can survive with this ;-) ? @nrussel: well I'm looking for an interactive and fast viewer, typically for images handled by `magick`, that can be embedded in a shiny app.